# Calling exec() or spawn(P_OVERLAY) unblocks the console; any way to keep the console blocked?

Tags: c, winapi, visual-c++, exec, spawn

Ina  console application, passing `_P_OVERLAY` to a [`spawn` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2.aspx) (which has the same effect as calling `exec`), destroys the current process.

This would be the desired behavior if it were not for the fact that doing so causes the *calling* process (which is often `cmd.exe`) to assume its callee has returned, whereas in reality the spawned sub-process of that callee is still running and therefore the caller should wait for that callee to terminate before continuing to use the console.

So, if the caller is `cmd.exe` (the command prompt), what happens is that as soon as the callee spawns the sub-process, the user is immediately prompted with the `C:\Users\User>` prompt, and becomes free to type in more commands, even though the sub-process is still running.

The best solution I have is to avoid terminating the current process until the child has terminated, but I'm wondering: is there any way to have the calling process wait on the spawned sub-processes before continuing when the callee has terminated?

Comment: So, why not use `exec()`?

Comment: @alk: What do you mean? The two behave exactly the same way.

Comment: Question not clear. You want wait for child process? Or want to control how `cmd.exe` behaves? Can't you use `CreateProcess`, or `ShellExecute[Ex]`?

Comment: @Ajay: Neither. I want the *caller* (whoever it may be; it may be `cmd.exe` or anything else) to wait for child processes to exist before continuing, even if the current process has terminated.

Comment: Ahok, I didn't test this. You want to say `exec()`ìng also shows the cmd-prompt immediately?

Comment: @Mehrdad, "exist before continuing" is vague. If you wrote it correctly, you need not to do anything.

Comment: @Ajay: That was a typo, it was supposed to say "wait for child processes to exit before continuing".

Comment: I assume **you** tested this. I however really wonder, as `exec()` does **not** create a new process, as opposed to `spawn()`, which does.

Comment: @alk: I have. Are you sure you're thinking about Windows and not Linux? Windows doesn't exactly have a fork/exec mechanism like Linux's; it behaves differently.

Comment: Jaja, I just reread about `_exec()` which indeed seems to do different things then the members of the `exec*()`-family of functions ... :-S

Comment: Waiting for child processes to finish requires tinkering with job objects on Windows, CreateJobObject() to get started.

Comment: @HansPassant: I was already looking into that actually, but I don't know what to do with the job objects. What do I do?

Comment: @alk: in Windows, exec() always creates a new process.  Windows does not provide any way to change which executable a process is running, if you want to run another executable you have to start a new process to run it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this - if you want `cmd.exe` to wait for your child to exit, then *you* need to wait for your child to exit.

The reason is that when `cmd.exe` launches your process it receives a process handle; it then waits for that process handle to become signaled.  Most other parents (for example, the C runtime library) will behave the same way.  Process handles are signaled when the process they refer to exits, and there is no way to change that behaviour.

Workaround: presumably you are using _P_OVERLAY because you're porting from UNIX code.  If there is too much code to conveniently change all of the instances to wait for the child before exiting, you could start a child process as soon as your process starts, and run all of the UNIX-based code in the child.  In this model, the only thing the top-level process does is to wait for the rest of the process tree to exit.  (You can use a job object to keep track of the process tree.)

Comment: I'm afraid there is almost never any reason to want to do this in native Windows code.  :-)